# Delphi: how to use ComponentCount in a public function?

Tags: class, delphi, components

I have this function below that uses ComponetCount, It is in a Form1 when I use this function in another Form, putting in Form2 uses in the Form1, it brings the number of Componetes of Form1 and not of Form2, how do I get around this problem? Follows function:

```
function Form1.getgridId(KeyField: String): string;
var
  i: Integer;
  id: string;

begin

  for i := 0 to ComponentCount -1 do
  begin
    if Components[i] is TCustomDBGrid then
    id:= TCustomDBGrid(Components[i]).DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName(KeyField).AsString;
  end;
  Result := id;

end;
```

**ANS (in my specific case) - With help of all:**

```
function getgridId(KeyField: String): string;
var
  i: Integer;
  id: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to Screen.ActiveForm.ComponentCount -1 do
  begin
    if Screen.ActiveForm.Components[i] is TCustomDBGrid then
      id := TCustomDBGrid(Screen.ActiveForm.Components[i]).DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName(KeyField).AsString;
  end;
  Result := id;

end;
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What class are you trying to instantiate? How does this code relate to your question? What units are you talking about?

Comment: Components are on a form or similar, not on a unit. So pass that form (which has already been instantiated?) to the function and iterate its components. Or pass the grid itself and do not iterate?

Comment: Are you sure you want the value from the **last** `TDBGrid` found?

Comment: I edited the question for clarity. @RobKennedy

Comment: What are you trying to say with "number of components in UnitX"? `TComponent.ComponentCount` has **nothing** to do with the unit

Comment: @FreeConsulting yes.

Comment: Did you see my comment?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I saw sorry. What would be the argument in the function? I did not want to pass the form because I wanted something generic. Or I could create a getformname type function.

Comment: While your solution you put in your question might work for you, that's a very dirty approach to this. Now you're relying on the active form, how sure are you that this particular form will be active when you need this?

Comment: Ok you're right, thanks. In my case it works because I'm calling the function in a form that will always be active until you close it (modal). So be warned @JerryDodge for those who need it.

Comment: @JerryDodge do you have a tip to do this more generic?

Comment: Well I would need to understand first why you decided to go about iterating controls in such a manner. Think of scalability. How easy will it be expand on such code? You need to use variables that explicitly reference one of these instances. As the answer by Remy explains, you need to explicitly specify which instance you intend on iterating.

Comment: On second thought I will not need to make this interaction because the form will have only one DBGrid, I created a function to get the ID when I click on any row in the DBGrid, so I want this function to be generic as it will be used in other forms .

Comment: Another way is to create a function to get the name of the active form and pass argument to the main function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are asking for requires adding a parameter to the function to know which Form to iterate:

```
function getgridId(Form: TForm; KeyField: String): string;
var
  i: Integer;
  id: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to Form.ComponentCount -1 do
  begin
    if Form.Components[i] is TCustomDBGrid then
      id := TCustomDBGrid(Form.Components[i]).DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName(KeyField).AsString;
  end;
  Result := id;
end;
```

Then, when each Form needs to call the function, it can pass it's `Self` pointer as the 1st parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I thought the componentcount would automatically recognize the form in which the function was called. I think Delphi has a getformname function but can not remember where.

Comment: Screen.ActiveForm to get TForm or .name to get string :D

Comment: @Artur_Indio: `ComponentCount`/`Components[]` *do* recognize which form they are called on. You made your function be a member of the `Form1` class, and you were using the function's `Self` parameter to access `ComponentCount`/`Components[]`, so you were always calling the function using a `Form1` object pointer, thus iterating through `Form1`'s components, even if the function was actually being called from `Form2`.  To iterate `Form2`'s components, you would have to access `ComponentCount`/`Components[]` using a `Form2` object pointer instead, which you were not doing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will refine my function.